# Long indexes style with imakeidx

Tags: indentation, indexing, imakeidx

I'm using imakeidx package:

```
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\indexsetup{othercode=\small}
\makeindex[program=makeindex,columns=2,intoc=true,options={-s index_style.ist}]
```

With style:

```
    headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\large\\sffamily\\bfseries "
heading_suffix "}\\nopagebreak\n"
delim_0 " \\dotfill "
delim_1 " \\dotfill "
delim_2 " \\dotfill "
```

But I have a few longer indexes and they are line breaking with indent. How can I modify your script to get rid of this indents?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a full (yet minimal) code?

Comment: entries in an index are list items.  list items are usually indented, and that format is usually defined by the document class.  in `imakeidx`, the only reference to this code is the line `\let\item\@idxitem`.  to redefine that (and if not properly "quarantined", it will affect *all* lists in your document), you will have to redefine the indentation used by`\@idxitem`.

Comment: I don't have other lists in this document. How can I redefine this indentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding

```
\makeatletter
\def\@idxitem{\par\hangindent 0pt}
\makeatother
```

in the preamble should do what you want.

Comment: Or just `\def\@idxitem{\par}`